# How to create a node list with appendchild JavaScript without Jquery

Tags: javascript

I need a bit help, because I am confused about the correct implementation for the JS appendChild for a very simple group list like:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to use the foreach but in somewhat it works because shows what contains in the Array, but I can't figure why is repeating inside of the 'list-group-item' repeating in the same list without separating to create a new and fresh

Let's say that I am creating a 'friend list' and show them in the HTML but the user can add new friends to the list so...

I created a basic HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="friendName" placeholder="Friend Name" required>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="friendBtn">Submit your friend</button>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wanted to make it a bit more dynamic to create a `<li>` for every friend in the array in my friendlist.js file:

```
// new array
let friendNameArray = ['marco','rafael'];
// get value from input textbox
let newFriend = document.getElementById('friendName');
// button listener event
let btnSubmitFriend = document.getElementById('friendBtn');


let newNodeListFriend = document.createElement("li");
let listFriendsGroup = document.querySelector('.list-group');
let friendNameText = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
let textNode;


btnSubmitFriend.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    friendNameArray.push(newFriend.value);
    preventEvent(event);
});

function cleanArrayHTML() {
    newNodeListFriend.innerHTML = "";
}
```

My idea is that in every half second it refresh the page to refill the new friend to the array and show them in the HTML wit this function setTimeout (note: I'm not using '**foreach**' and '**for**' at the same time, I tried to use one of them to see what is my error)

```
function start() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('running timeout');
        cleanArrayHTML();

        friendNameArray.forEach(list => {
            // then create the text node
             textNode = document.createTextNode(list);

            // friendNameText.innerHTML += list;
            // then append the Text node to the LI node.
            newNodeListFriend.className = 'list-group-item';
            newNodeListFriend.appendChild(textNode);
            // Finally append the LI node to the list.
            friendNameText.appendChild(newNodeListFriend);
        });

        for (let count = 0; count < friendNameArray.length; count++) {
            textNode = document.createTextNode(friendNameArray[count]);

            newNodeListFriend.className = 'list-group-item';
            newNodeListFriend.appendChild(textNode);

            // Finally append the LI node to the list.
            friendNameText.appendChild(newNodeListFriend);
        }

        // Again
        start();

        // Every .5 sec
    }, 500);
}

// Begins
start();
```

But in the debug it repeats like:

```
<li class=\"list-group-item\">marcorafael</li>
```

What I want is this way:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">marco</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">rafael</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may want to use a template library.

Comment: You might want to have a look into `insertAdjacentHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML, which was standardised for exactly this kind of purpose. Just say `beforeend` on the UL and insert it there. Or use something like `innerText`, or `innerHTML` (dangerous!).

Comment: @somethinghere Does your `dangerous` apply to only `innerHTML` or also to `innerText`. And why should it be (more?) dangerous compared to `insertAdjacentHTML`?

Comment: Dangerous only refers to `innerHTML` (as somebody might try to input a script), innerText will escape any dangerous aspects. Its technically true for `insertAdjascentHTML` as well, as it always is when inserting using content. Always lookout for what people might try to screw you over :)